# Which country is Paweł Błaszczak from?

Tags: history

Paweł Błaszczak composed music for several well known video games including "The Witcher" and "Dying Light". He also composed music for some movies, but I couldn't find his country of origin from a google search. Would anyone happen to know?

Comment: Haven't you heard about this wonderful invention called Google? http://www.pawelblaszczak.com/?lang=en&id=about_me

Comment: @alephzero that link says he graduated in and works in Poland, but not definitively that he's from Poland.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 10 second Google came up with Poland - at least that's where he went to uni.

Comment: So can I assume he's from Poland. Its very likely right?

Comment: More than likely a Polish name, studied at a uni where Polish would be the main language - no other info. is forthcoming, so yes. He has a facebook account. Ask!